# console.log function not working inside the express routes(node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to debug my express app using console.log but I am not getting any output in the terminal.

`app.js`:

```
var express     = require("express"),
    app         = express(),
    bodyParser  = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.get("/",function(req,res){
    console.log("landing page");
    res.send("landing page");
});

app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("Server started!!")
});
```

Output:

```
$ node app.js
Server started!!
```

Comment: The expected output is (1) `server started` (when the server starts), then (2) `landing page` (every time you request /, for example when opening `localhost:3000/` in your browser). What do you observe instead?

Comment: Welcome to SO! How are you starting your server?

Comment: screenshot of the terminal is attached

Comment: @NinoFiliu I have attached the terminal snapshot, please have a look into it

Comment: Are you requesting the page? Start your server then navigate to `localhost:3000`. What happens then?

Comment: @NinoFiliu yes I started server and navigated to localhost:3000 and the image attached is of the terminal after navigating to the page . There is no console.log output in the terminal.The only output that can be seen in the terminal is of app.listen

Comment: What do you see in your browser?

Comment: @NinoFiliu All my routes work fine. I am able to navigate to all the pages in browser but terminal is not giving cosole.log output